# How to change treemap ordering in D3plus

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

Is it possible to change ordering of tree map layout in d3plus. As far as I see its size based in default, however I want custom ordering according to name of rectangle elements in tree map. I tried the code below but doesn't work.

```
.order({'value':['rectname','rectid']})
```

Here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/kasimsert/wLvpph35/11/